# Mersenne vs Rand: Why do I get more total consecutive repetitions when using Mersenne compared to Rand? C++

Tags: c++, random, srand, mersenne-twister

I have this algorithm for shuffling, I am trying to replace the Rand with Mersenne as an enhancement since Mersenne is more efficient and produces much randomness compared to rand according to what I've searched. However, when comparing it side by side, I ran it for 5 times each and total the repetitions of each 5 cases, I get more repetition when using Mersenne than in Rand. Why is that? I'm new to programming, your help is appreciated. Thank you!

This is my code for using Mersenne

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

struct Element {
    int value;
    std::string attribute1;
    std::string attribute2;
    std::string attribute3;
    std::string attribute4;
    std::string attribute5;
    int count;
};

bool haveSameAttributes(const Element& elem1, const Element& elem2) {
    return (elem1.attribute1 == elem2.attribute1 &&
            elem1.attribute2 == elem2.attribute2 &&
            elem1.attribute3 == elem2.attribute3 &&
            elem1.attribute4 == elem2.attribute4 &&
            elem1.attribute5 == elem2.attribute5);
}

void enhancedShuffle(std::vector<Element>& rndnum, std::mt19937& gen) {

    int n = rndnum.size();
    int n1 = n;
    int j = n - 1;
    int attempts = 0;
    const int max_attempts = n1; // Maximum number of attempts allowed

    // Reset the count for all elements to 0
    for (Element& elem : rndnum) {
        elem.count = 0; // Assuming count is a member variable of Element
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // Using Mersenne Twister PRNG
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, n1 - 1);
        int x = dist(gen);
        rndnum[x].count++;

        if (i > 0) {
            // Check Element's Attributes (5) & Max Attempt to n1
            if ((rndnum[x].value == rndnum[j + 1].value || haveSameAttributes(rndnum[x], rndnum[j + 1])) && attempts < max_attempts) {
                int z = dist(gen);
                ++attempts;

                // Compare Selection Count of Elements
                if (rndnum[x].count > rndnum[i - 1].count && attempts < max_attempts) {
                    // Using Mersenne Twister PRNG
                    x = dist(gen);
                    ++attempts;
                    rndnum[x].count++;
                }

                if ((x + z) >= j) {
                    x = (x + z) - j;
                } else {
                    x = x + z;
                }

            }
        }

        std::swap(rndnum[x], rndnum[j]);
        --n1;
        --j;
    }
}

// For counting the repetitions throughout the shuffled list
int countConsecutiveRepetitions(const std::vector<Element>& rndnum) {
    int consecutiveRepetitions = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < rndnum.size(); ++i) {
        if (haveSameAttributes(rndnum[i], rndnum[i - 1])) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions;
        }
    }
    return consecutiveRepetitions;
}

std::vector<int> countConsecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute(const std::vector<Element>& rndnum) {
    int consecutiveRepetitions1 = 0;
    int consecutiveRepetitions2 = 0;
    int consecutiveRepetitions3 = 0;
    int consecutiveRepetitions4 = 0;
    int consecutiveRepetitions5 = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < rndnum.size(); ++i) {
        if (rndnum[i].attribute1 == rndnum[i - 1].attribute1) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions1;
        }
        if (rndnum[i].attribute2 == rndnum[i - 1].attribute2) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions2;
        }
        if (rndnum[i].attribute3 == rndnum[i - 1].attribute3) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions3;
        }
        if (rndnum[i].attribute4 == rndnum[i - 1].attribute4) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions4;
        }
        if (rndnum[i].attribute5 == rndnum[i - 1].attribute5) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions5;
        }
    }
    int totalConsecutiveAttributes = consecutiveRepetitions1 + consecutiveRepetitions2 + consecutiveRepetitions3 + consecutiveRepetitions4 + consecutiveRepetitions5;
    return {consecutiveRepetitions1, consecutiveRepetitions2, consecutiveRepetitions3, consecutiveRepetitions4, consecutiveRepetitions5, totalConsecutiveAttributes};
}

int main() {
    const int desiredSize = 50;
    const int numIterations = 1000;
    std::vector<Element> baseList = {
        {1, "Dragon", "Large", "Long", "Shoes", "Green"},
        {2, "Dragon", "Small", "Average", "Boots", "Green"},
        {3, "Dragon", "Small", "Short", "Slippers", "Red"},
        {4, "Dragon", "Medium", "Average", "Shoes", "White"},
        {5, "Dragon", "Large", "Long", "Boots", "Red"},
    };

    int totalConsecutiveRepetitions = 0;
    std::vector<int> totalConsecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute(5, 0);

    auto seed = static_cast<unsigned>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    std::mt19937 gen(seed);

    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < numIterations; ++iteration) {
        std::vector<Element> rndnum;

        // Repeat the base list to achieve the desired size
        while (rndnum.size() < desiredSize) {
            rndnum.insert(rndnum.end(), baseList.begin(), baseList.end());
        }

        // Trim the excess elements
        rndnum.resize(desiredSize);

        enhancedShuffle(rndnum, gen);

        // Display each element with its attributes (Optional)
//        for (const auto& element : rndnum) {
//            std::cout << "Value: " << element.value
//                      << ", Attribute1: " << element.attribute1
//                      << ", Attribute2: " << element.attribute2
//                      << ", Attribute3: " << element.attribute3
//                      << ", Attribute4: " << element.attribute4
//                      << ", Attribute5: " << element.attribute5
//                      << ", Count: " << element.count << std::endl;
//        }

        int consecutiveRepetitions = countConsecutiveRepetitions(rndnum);
        totalConsecutiveRepetitions += consecutiveRepetitions;

        std::vector<int> consecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute = countConsecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute(rndnum);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            totalConsecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute[i] += consecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute[i];
        }

        std::cout << "\nConsecutive repetitions in iteration " << iteration + 1 << ": " << consecutiveRepetitions << std::endl;
        std::cout << "---------------------------------------------\n";

    }

    int totalAttributeCounts = 0;
    for (int count : totalConsecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute) {
        totalAttributeCounts += count;
    }

    std::cout << "\nTotal Consecutive repetitions across all iterations: " <<  totalConsecutiveRepetitions << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

RESULTS: MERSENNE

- CASE 1: 2317
- CASE 2: 2222
- CASE 3: 2325
- CASE 4: 2331
- CASE 5: 2314

Now this is my code for using Rand

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Element {
    int value;
    std::string attribute1;
    std::string attribute2;
    std::string attribute3;
    std::string attribute4;
    std::string attribute5;
    int count;
};

bool haveSameAttributes(const Element& elem1, const Element& elem2) {
    return (elem1.attribute1 == elem2.attribute1 &&
            elem1.attribute2 == elem2.attribute2 &&
            elem1.attribute3 == elem2.attribute3 &&
            elem1.attribute4 == elem2.attribute4 &&
            elem1.attribute5 == elem2.attribute5);
}

void enhancedShuffle(std::vector<Element>& rndnum) {

    int n = rndnum.size();
    int n1 = n;
    int j = n - 1;
    int attempts = 0;
    const int max_attempts = n1; // Maximum number of attempts allowed

    // Reset the count for all elements to 0
    for (Element& elem : rndnum) {
        elem.count = 0; // Assuming count is a member variable of Element
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // Using Mersenne Twister PRNG
        int x = rand() % n1;
        rndnum[x].count++;

        if (i > 0) {
            // Check Element's Attributes (5) & Max Attempt to n1
            if ((rndnum[x].value == rndnum[j + 1].value || haveSameAttributes(rndnum[x], rndnum[j + 1])) && attempts < max_attempts) {
                int z = rand() % n1;
                ++attempts;

                // Compare Selection Count of Elements
                if (rndnum[x].count > rndnum[i - 1].count && attempts < max_attempts) {
                    // Using Mersenne Twister PRNG
                    x = rand() % n1;
                    ++attempts;
                    rndnum[x].count++;
                }

                if ((x + z) >= j) {
                    x = (x + z) - j;
                } else {
                    x = x + z;
                }


            }
        }

        std::swap(rndnum[x], rndnum[j]);
        --n1;
        --j;
    }
}

// For counting the repetitions throughout the shuffled list
int countConsecutiveRepetitions(const std::vector<Element>& rndnum) {
    int consecutiveRepetitions = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < rndnum.size(); ++i) {
        if (haveSameAttributes(rndnum[i], rndnum[i - 1])) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions;
        }
    }
    return consecutiveRepetitions;
}

std::vector<int> countConsecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute(const std::vector<Element>& rndnum) {
    int consecutiveRepetitions1 = 0;
    int consecutiveRepetitions2 = 0;
    int consecutiveRepetitions3 = 0;
    int consecutiveRepetitions4 = 0;
    int consecutiveRepetitions5 = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < rndnum.size(); ++i) {
        if (rndnum[i].attribute1 == rndnum[i - 1].attribute1) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions1;
        }
        if (rndnum[i].attribute2 == rndnum[i - 1].attribute2) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions2;
        }
        if (rndnum[i].attribute3 == rndnum[i - 1].attribute3) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions3;
        }
        if (rndnum[i].attribute4 == rndnum[i - 1].attribute4) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions4;
        }
        if (rndnum[i].attribute5 == rndnum[i - 1].attribute5) {
            ++consecutiveRepetitions5;
        }
    }
    int totalConsecutiveAttributes = consecutiveRepetitions1 + consecutiveRepetitions2 + consecutiveRepetitions3 + consecutiveRepetitions4 + consecutiveRepetitions5;
    return {consecutiveRepetitions1, consecutiveRepetitions2, consecutiveRepetitions3, consecutiveRepetitions4, consecutiveRepetitions5, totalConsecutiveAttributes};
}

    int main() {
    const int desiredSize = 50;
    const int numIterations = 1000;
    std::vector<Element> baseList = {
        {1, "Dragon", "Large", "Long", "Shoes", "Green"},
        {2, "Dragon", "Small", "Average", "Boots", "Green"},
        {3, "Dragon", "Small", "Short", "Slippers", "Red"},
        {4, "Dragon", "Medium", "Average", "Shoes", "White"},
        {5, "Dragon", "Large", "Long", "Boots", "Red"},
    };

    int totalConsecutiveRepetitions = 0;
    std::vector<int> totalConsecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute(5, 0);

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));

    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < numIterations; ++iteration) {
        std::vector<Element> rndnum;



        // Repeat the base list to achieve the desired size
        while (rndnum.size() < desiredSize) {
            rndnum.insert(rndnum.end(), baseList.begin(), baseList.end());
        }

        // Trim the excess elements
        rndnum.resize(desiredSize);

        enhancedShuffle(rndnum);

        // Display each element with its attributes (Optional)
//        for (const auto& element : rndnum) {
//            std::cout << "Value: " << element.value
//                      << ", Attribute1: " << element.attribute1
//                      << ", Attribute2: " << element.attribute2
//                      << ", Attribute3: " << element.attribute3
//                      << ", Attribute4: " << element.attribute4
//                      << ", Attribute5: " << element.attribute5
//                      << ", Count: " << element.count << std::endl;
//        }

        int consecutiveRepetitions = countConsecutiveRepetitions(rndnum);
        totalConsecutiveRepetitions += consecutiveRepetitions;

        std::vector<int> consecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute = countConsecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute(rndnum);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            totalConsecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute[i] += consecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute[i];
        }

        std::cout << "\nConsecutive repetitions in iteration " << iteration + 1 << ": " << consecutiveRepetitions << std::endl;
        std::cout << "---------------------------------------------\n";

    }

    int totalAttributeCounts = 0;
    for (int count : totalConsecutiveRepetitionsPerAttribute) {
        totalAttributeCounts += count;
    }

    std::cout << "\nTotal Consecutive repetitions across all iterations: " << totalConsecutiveRepetitions << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

RESULTS: RAND

- CASE 1: 2292
- CASE 2: 2222
- CASE 3: 2231
- CASE 4: 2243
- CASE 5: 2268

COMPARISON: TOTAL CONSECUTIVE REPETITIONS PER CASE

MERSENNE:

- CASE 1: 2317
- CASE 2: 2222
- CASE 3: 2325
- CASE 4: 2331
- CASE 5: 2314

RAND

- CASE 1: 2292
- CASE 2: 2222
- CASE 3: 2231
- CASE 4: 2243
- CASE 5: 2268

The results for both are inconsistent, there are times when I test again Mersenne seems to be lower and Rand appears higher, but most of the time the Rand has much lower consecutive repetitions. I was expecting to have lower results when using Mersenne. Does that mean that Mersenne is not an enhancement in my application to use?

Comment: I don't think that this is as scientific as using software that specializes in this kind of testing such as diehard suite or the suite of the German BSI. Those are for cryptographic algorithms, but in principle they test the quality of the distribution. Note that these are normally run on multiple GiB of data.

Comment: Frequency of repetitions, consecutive or otherwise, is not a measure of randomness nor of quality of a random number generator.   You need to look at properties of the distribution of values produced.  Whatever the distribution is, there is always a non-zero chance of repetition, and of consecutive repetitions -  a generator with no repetitions (or no consecutive repetitions) would often be pretty poor by various measures.

Comment: Thank you for these comments! What do you guys suggest that I do to test that using Mersenne here is better than using Rand, not basing on the frequency of repetitions?

Comment: As both previous comments have noted (in different ways), test statistical properties of the *distribution* of values produced.   Since you haven't specified (realistic) requirements of your program, it's impossible to give more specific advice.

Comment: My program is intended to increase the apparent randomness by reducing the number of consecutive repetitions of elements with the same attributes.

for example element 1 has these properties (dragon, lizard, short, average, green)
then element 3 appeared after element 1 with the same properties or attributes.

and implementing mersenne is one of my approach to reduce this. This algorithm makes the shuffling bias to make it appear more random to the user. Bias in a way that elements with the same attributes won't appear consecutively

Comment: I applied the mersenne and rand when it comes to selecting a random indices for shuffling

Comment: Why do you equate "apparent randomness" with "smaller number of consecutive repetitions"?      If you're seeking a random choice of (say) what type of critter is coming through a door,  it is actually quite reasonable that two critters of the same type sometimes come through, one after the other.   People are quite used to the notion of throwing a die, and (say) getting two consecutive equal values (in fact, on every throw, there is a one in six chance that the value thrown will be the same as the previous one).

Comment: And, if you're doing shuffling,  just make sure the set you're shuffling has unique values, and has a large enough set of values.   Then it doesn't matter whether the random number generator produces consecutive values the same - you're going to be calling the generator multiple times to shuffle anyway - and, unless the number of consecutive repeats is comparable with (a significant proportion of) the number of values being shuffled, the impact of the repeats will be insignificant anyway.

Comment: This is the paper I based it from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320677516_Planned_Random_Algorithm

I am to enhance this algorithm by implementing mersenne instead of rand

Comment: I'd suggest taking guidance from that paper with a large dose of caution. Sentence two of their abstract is the opposite of true, which for me as a reader casts doubt on anything that follows. They also acknowledge in "Drawbacks" on the last page that their algorithm makes results look more like what humans expect by biasing them away from what true randomness would produce, and that this is most noticeable with small datasets (such as yours).

Comment: I tried to get the full text but I couldn't. It seems only page 1 and 8 or so are posted and that in scanned form. I don't think it is just the second sentence is nonsense, the whole abstract is one big shitshow. And to be honest it is the first paper I see that dares to reference not just Wikipedia, but also the f-ing Telegraph. Seriously?

Comment: @Peter "Frequency of repetitions, consecutive or otherwise, is not a measure of randomness nor of quality of a random number generator." It is. Birthday test(s) is pretty typical for RNG test suites